# Anyone can help me to solve this prob : Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php

> I have prob with the time after the subtraction to be inserted into database

```
$time = new DateTime('08:10:00');
$timein = new DateTime('17:05:00');
$newtime = $timein->diff($time);
$sql = "UPDATE staff_attendance SET total_working_time='$result' WHERE id='$a_id'";
```

Comment: you'll need to post more of the code, but i'm guessing you're directly interpolating the datetime object in the string sql statement you're making, try to use the method `->format()` first to convert it to string then use it in the sql statement

Comment: what is `$result` you are using in SQL query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch difference and then convert to `H:i:s`, like this:

```
$hour = $newtime->format('%h');
$minute = $newtime->format('%i');
$second = $newtime->format('%s');

$year = $newtime->format('%y');
$month = $newtime->format('%m');
$day = $newtime->format('%d');

$time = $hour.':'.$minute.':'.$second; // H:i:s
```

https://paiza.io/projects/QKxRTpDEo6zRjooQAfdONQ?language=php